# How to say if a word tree is similar to another?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, nlp

I want to know when a tree is similar to part of another, for instance when

- When did Beyonce start becoming popular?

is partly included in the following sentences :

- She started becoming popular in the late 1990s (1<sup>st</sup> case)
- She rose to fame in the late 1990s (2<sup>nd</sup> case)

I am able to say when one text is strictly included included in another : I created a class that transforms spaCy array to tree and I show later how to transform text to spaCy.

```
class WordTree:
    '''Tree for spaCy dependency parsing array'''
    def __init__(self, tree, is_subtree=False):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param array: The array contening the dependency
        :param parent: The parent of the array if exists
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = tree.label().split('_')[0] # the first element of the tree # We are going to add the synonyms as well.

        for subtree in tree:
            if type(subtree) == Tree:
                # Iterate through the depth of the subtree.
                t = WordTree(subtree, True)
                t.parent=tree.label().split('_')[0]
            elif type(subtree) == str:
                surface_form = subtree.split('_')[0]
                self.children.append(surface_form)
```

And I can tell when one sentence is included in another tahnks to the following functions :

```
def isSubtree(T,S):
    if S is None:
        return True
    if T is None:
        return False
    if areIdentical(T, S):
        return True
    return any(isSubtree(c, S) for c in T.children)

def areIdentical(root1, root2):
    '''
    function to say if two roots are identical
    '''
    # Base Case
    if root1 is None and root2 is None:
        return True
    if root1 is None or root2 is None:
        return False

    # Check if the data of both roots their and children are the same
    return (root1.data == root2.data and
            ((areIdentical(child1 , child2))
             for child1, child2 in zip(root1.children, root2.children)))
```

Indeed, for instance :

```
# first tree creation
text = "start becoming popular"
textSpacy = spacy_nlp(text)
treeText = nltk_spacy_tree(textSpacy)
t = WordTree(treeText[0])

# second tree creation
question = "When did Beyonce start becoming popular?"
questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
q = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])

# tree comparison
isSubtree(t,q)
```

Returns `True`. Therefore when can I say that a tree is partly included (1<sup>st</sup> case) in another or similar (2<sup>nd</sup> case) to another ?

Comment: I guess by "word tree" you mean sentence dependency parse tree. The problem in your examples is not just tree comparison it is about lexical semantics, anaphora resolution, and semsntic of the sentence! You probably can see that there is zero overlap in tokens of 2nd case and the question. "Rose to fame" vs "start becoming popular". Even the 1st case, "started" is not the same as "start" also you should ask yourself: doesn't it matter if you replace "she" with another word?

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks for your comment. Word trees are issued from dependency parse tree in array form.The problem is hard but interesting. For 1st case, I deal with it with it with [stemming](https://pythonprogramming.net/stemming-nltk-tutorial/) : `started` would become `start`. For lexical semantics I try to find synonyms of each word. I will maybe try later to add only the synonyms of those that are important through TF-IDF. I don't know what anaphora resolution and how to do the semantic of the whole sentence.